# BeautifulSoup not scraping all HREF links for this website....retunrs no

Tags: python, web-scraping, href

for context I am trying to get all the links from this website to create a repository of all the associated products.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


baseurl = "https://www.ercotires.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

for x in range(1,6):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged={x}', verify = False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is here. When running this code (slightly modified) it returns all the products of interest?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


baseurl = "https://www.ercotires.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

for x in range(1,6):
    r = requests.get('https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/', params={'swoof': '1','paged': x,}, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
tel:+59326009000
https://www.ercotires.com/
None
None
https://www.ercotires.com/servicios/
https://www.ercotires.com/promocion/
https://www.ercotires.com/cobertura-total-activacion/
https://www.ercotires.com/blog/
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03561150000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03561170000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508920000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508880000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508670000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509060000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508890000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508630000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508650000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508940000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04511260000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508900000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508640000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508960000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508660000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508720000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506030000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15505980000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508690000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508930000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15543440000/
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/18/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/19/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/20/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/cambio-de-direccion/
https://www.ercotires.com/olvido-de-contrasena/
https://www.ercotires.com/seguimiento-de-orden/
https://www.pagoplux.com/
https://www.facebook.com/ErcoTiresEcuadorOficial
https://www.instagram.com/ercotires/
https://www.ercotires.com/condiciones-de-uso/
https://www.ercotires.com/terminos-y-condiciones-cobertura-total/
https://www.ercotires.com/politica-de-privacidad/
https://www.ercotires.com/sitemap/
https://www.ercotires.com/informacion-legal/
https://www.ercotires.com/contacto/
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_marca=continental
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&pa_marca=general-tire&paged=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=automovil
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=camioneta
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=suv
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=van
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=13
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=14
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=15
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=16
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=17
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=18
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=19
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=20
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=21
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=22
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=23
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=24
#
tel:+59326009000
https://www.ercotires.com/
None
None
https://www.ercotires.com/servicios/
https://www.ercotires.com/promocion/
https://www.ercotires.com/cobertura-total-activacion/
https://www.ercotires.com/blog/
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508700000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508950000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509020000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508730000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508910000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508680000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508970000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508710000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03588920000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03507510000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15507040000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508990000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508740000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506040000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03505260000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03573420000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15505990000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506050000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508750000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509000000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509030000/
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/1/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/1/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/5/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/18/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/19/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/20/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/cambio-de-direccion/
https://www.ercotires.com/olvido-de-contrasena/
https://www.ercotires.com/seguimiento-de-orden/
https://www.pagoplux.com/
https://www.facebook.com/ErcoTiresEcuadorOficial
https://www.instagram.com/ercotires/
https://www.ercotires.com/condiciones-de-uso/
https://www.ercotires.com/terminos-y-condiciones-cobertura-total/
https://www.ercotires.com/politica-de-privacidad/
https://www.ercotires.com/sitemap/
https://www.ercotires.com/informacion-legal/
https://www.ercotires.com/contacto/
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_marca=continental
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&pa_marca=general-tire&paged=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=automovil
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=camioneta
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=suv
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=van
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=13
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=14
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=15
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=16
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=17
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=18
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=19
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=20
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=21
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=22
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=23
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=24
#
tel:+59326009000
https://www.ercotires.com/
None
None
https://www.ercotires.com/servicios/
https://www.ercotires.com/promocion/
https://www.ercotires.com/cobertura-total-activacion/
https://www.ercotires.com/blog/
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03519600000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03589110000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03580670000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04511160000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04514020000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04512160000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04511170000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04516600000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04514010000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03562300000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03574830000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03580380000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03576330000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15507050000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506560000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03500690000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03527370000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03508150000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15507030000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15507070000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15508760000/
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/1/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/5/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/6/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/18/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/19/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/20/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/cambio-de-direccion/
https://www.ercotires.com/olvido-de-contrasena/
https://www.ercotires.com/seguimiento-de-orden/
https://www.pagoplux.com/
https://www.facebook.com/ErcoTiresEcuadorOficial
https://www.instagram.com/ercotires/
https://www.ercotires.com/condiciones-de-uso/
https://www.ercotires.com/terminos-y-condiciones-cobertura-total/
https://www.ercotires.com/politica-de-privacidad/
https://www.ercotires.com/sitemap/
https://www.ercotires.com/informacion-legal/
https://www.ercotires.com/contacto/
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_marca=continental
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&pa_marca=general-tire&paged=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=automovil
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=camioneta
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=suv
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=van
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=13
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=14
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=15
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=16
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=17
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=18
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=19
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=20
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=21
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=22
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=23
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=24
#
tel:+59326009000
https://www.ercotires.com/
None
None
https://www.ercotires.com/servicios/
https://www.ercotires.com/promocion/
https://www.ercotires.com/cobertura-total-activacion/
https://www.ercotires.com/blog/
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03588610000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506060000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03561050000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03580030000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03508090000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15506540000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15505970000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509010000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03564020000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03502610000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03589100000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15509040000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04511250000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04514050000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03589320000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04509960000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04503590000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04514060000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03567130000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03516290000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03566880000/
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/1/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/5/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/6/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/7/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/18/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/19/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/20/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/5/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/cambio-de-direccion/
https://www.ercotires.com/olvido-de-contrasena/
https://www.ercotires.com/seguimiento-de-orden/
https://www.pagoplux.com/
https://www.facebook.com/ErcoTiresEcuadorOficial
https://www.instagram.com/ercotires/
https://www.ercotires.com/condiciones-de-uso/
https://www.ercotires.com/terminos-y-condiciones-cobertura-total/
https://www.ercotires.com/politica-de-privacidad/
https://www.ercotires.com/sitemap/
https://www.ercotires.com/informacion-legal/
https://www.ercotires.com/contacto/
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_marca=continental
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&pa_marca=general-tire&paged=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=automovil
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=camioneta
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=suv
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=van
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=13
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=14
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=15
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=16
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=17
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=18
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=19
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=20
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=21
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=22
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=23
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=24
#
tel:+59326009000
https://www.ercotires.com/
None
None
https://www.ercotires.com/servicios/
https://www.ercotires.com/promocion/
https://www.ercotires.com/cobertura-total-activacion/
https://www.ercotires.com/blog/
#
#
#
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03580820000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15507080000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03112520000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03586580000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15492640000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03562580000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03507160000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03566500000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15571340000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03568980000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03503400000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03564700000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03589310000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03592890000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04490930000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03589340000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15571270000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-15571410000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04490920000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-04503600000/
https://www.ercotires.com/producto/sku-03588890000/
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/1/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/2/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/3/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/4/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/6/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/7/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/8/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/18/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/19/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/20/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/page/6/?swoof=1
https://www.ercotires.com/cambio-de-direccion/
https://www.ercotires.com/olvido-de-contrasena/
https://www.ercotires.com/seguimiento-de-orden/
https://www.pagoplux.com/
https://www.facebook.com/ErcoTiresEcuadorOficial
https://www.instagram.com/ercotires/
https://www.ercotires.com/condiciones-de-uso/
https://www.ercotires.com/terminos-y-condiciones-cobertura-total/
https://www.ercotires.com/politica-de-privacidad/
https://www.ercotires.com/sitemap/
https://www.ercotires.com/informacion-legal/
https://www.ercotires.com/contacto/
#
#
#
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_marca=continental
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&pa_marca=general-tire&paged=1
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=automovil
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=camioneta
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=suv
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&product_tag=van
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=13
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=14
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=15
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=16
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=17
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=18
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=19
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=20
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=21
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=22
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=23
https://www.ercotires.com/tienda/?swoof=1&paged=1&pa_rin=24
#
```